# Product of a positive-definite function by a (simply) positive function: under which conditions is it also positive-definite?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

If $F(x)$ is a positive-definite function (possibly complex), is there any condition on $F$ that would ensure that  $e{}^{\frac{+x^{2}}{2}}F(x)$ is also a positive-definite function?

Here, we assume that the function  $e{}^{\frac{+x^{2}}{2}}F(x)$ is  a $L{}_{2}$ function.

Such product is obviously not positive-definite in the general case but could we say that the product is positive-definite for a specific type/category of functions $F(x)$ or if $F(x)$ fulfil some specific conditions?

It would be helpful if someone could point me to a reference that address such questions. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by positive definite function? Is $F$ matrix valued?

Comment: I consider the definition in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_function or alternatively, a Positive-definite function is a function whose (possibly inverse-) Fourier transform is a positive real function, by Bochner's theorem.